# Insertion Sort sorts array halfway

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I am reading a book of DS and Algortihms. I saw an algorithm named insertion sort and then tried to apply that in c++. When I sort the array, the first element of the array remains at the place it was previously while the other elements go to their appropriate place! I can't understand what's happeing.
My code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void vec_in(vector<unsigned>& vec, unsigned size);
void vec_out(vector<unsigned> vec);

int main(){
    vector<unsigned> vec;
    unsigned size;
    cout<<"SIZE : ";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"ARRAY : ";
    vec_in(vec,size);
    cout<<endl;
    for(unsigned j=1; j<size; j++){
        unsigned key = vec[j];
        unsigned i=j-1;
        cout<<key<<endl;
        while(i>0&&vec[i]>key){
            vec[i+1]=vec[i];
            i--;
        }
        vec[i+1]=key;
    }
    cout<<"SORTED ARRAY : ";
    vec_out(vec);

} 

void vec_in(vector<unsigned>& vec, unsigned size){
    for(unsigned i=0; i<size; i++){
        unsigned in;
        cin>>in;
        vec.push_back(in);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void vec_out(vector<unsigned> vec){
    for(unsigned i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){ 
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    } 
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I tried this code with many samples the result remains same : the first element is never sorted.

Comment: You have not initialized i in `vec_in`

Comment: @P.W nothing happens even after initializing i

Comment: oh right, sorry ;)

Comment: Have you tried debugging code, printing what happens at end of loop?

Comment: @SiddharthMishra: Update the question accordingly with the value you have initialized it to.

Comment: Try changing `while(i>0...` into `while(i>=0...`.

Comment: @Melon Yes I tried doing that too...

Comment: And...? How did he vector look/change at end of each loop?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That gives me segmentation fault

Comment: @Melon When I did that the array wasn't sorted at all due to some reason

Comment: As others have suggested, you must debug. Start with an array of one element, then two, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `while(i>0&&vec[i]>key){` by `while(i>=0&&vec[i]>key){`. In this case `i` can get negative. Thus, it needs to be singed, i.e., [this code](http://cpp.sh/6bbzd) works.

If you want to stay with your types, you can replace all occurences of `i` with `i-1` and obtain

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void vec_in(vector<unsigned>& vec, unsigned size);
void vec_out(vector<unsigned> vec);

int main(){
    vector<unsigned> vec;
    unsigned size;
    cout<<"SIZE : ";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"ARRAY : ";
    vec_in(vec,size);
    cout<<endl;
    for(unsigned j=1; j<size; j++){
        unsigned key = vec[j];
        unsigned i=j;
        cout<<key<<endl;
        while(i>0&&vec[i-1]>key){
            vec[i]=vec[i-1];
            i--;
        }
        vec[i]=key;
    }
    cout<<"SORTED ARRAY : ";
    vec_out(vec);

} 

void vec_in(vector<unsigned>& vec, unsigned size){
    for(unsigned i=0; i<size; i++){
        unsigned in;
        cin>>in;
        vec.push_back(in);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void vec_out(vector<unsigned> vec){
    for(unsigned i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){ 
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
    } 
    cout<<endl;
}
```

[which works as well](http://cpp.sh/5ntss).

Note that your approach need *N^2* steps (where *N* is the size of the vector). There are much better approaches, which do it in only *log(N) N* steps, like quick sort. The standard library implements such an algorithm. Thus, you should *always* use `std::sort` for sorting.

Comment: Thanks this code worked but I can't find out what is the reason behind my code not running correctly... even when i changed everything to int... Also I know that this sort is not that efficient but the book says that this is good for small arrays and is faster in that case!

Comment: @Handy999 - I deleted my prior comments. I'll delete this one later.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we have only two elements: `4` and `3`.

Now, what happens when `for` loop is entered.

```
    for(unsigned j=1; j<size; j++){
        unsigned key = vec[j];         /* key := 3      */
        unsigned i=j;                  /* i := 1        */
        cout<<key<<endl;               /* print(3)      */
        while(i>0&&vec[i-1]>key){      /* i > 0 (false) */
            vec[i]=vec[i-1];
            i--;
        }
        vec[i]=key;
    }
```

The `while` loop that does the sorting is not entered. This will always happen when trying to compare `vec[0]` to `vec[1]`.

As a rule of thumb, please do the following tests first time:

```
1) empty vector
2) vector with one element
3) vector with two elements a) sorted acending b) sorted descending
...
```

They will allow you to quickly find minor bugs.

Comment: I updated the code making all vectors and variables of type int and also updated the condition for entering the while loop to (i>=0&&vec[i]>=key) but the output remained the same.

Comment: If you updated to ```while(i>=0&&vec[i]>=key)``` the ```i>=0``` statement is always true, as ```i``` is of ```unsigned``` type. This can lead to accessing ```vec[MAX_UINT]``` element which does not exist.